# "iPad is disabled, connect to iTunes"

Tags: ipad, ios

Trying to turn on my kids' iPad which has been off for a few months.

Tried several of my 'usual' passcodes, but iPad became 'disabled' before I could try them all.

Now it's "iPad is disabled, connect to iTunes"

Connecting to iTunes via hold-home-and-plug-in-USB pops up iTunes with "Restore" or "Update".

Do NOT want to lose all data, there are probably photos on there that are not backed up.

Is there ANYTHING I can do?

I'm not even sure which version of iOS is on there, but it's 8.something...

If I could just get a few more attempts to enter PIN, I would figure it out eventually.

Can I jailbreak it in this condition? Somehow pull the data before Restoring/Updating?

HELP!

Answer (score 2):

I heard that Jailbreaking it may work, it's probably your only option to salvage the data on the iPad. Normally, I would **never** even suggest Jailbreaking, but in this case, it's probably your only option. I've never done it and have no interest whatsoever in Jailbreaking, so I can't tell how to do it, what to use, or even if it will for sure work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: If a person wanted to jailbreak a locked ipad (which I obviously don't) and that person didn't know which ios version was on the ipad, how would they proceed? Is there a jailbreak for all 8.x ?

Comment: If you were to just connect it to iTunes, not restoring it, I think that it would tell you the version of iOS it's running. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: I tried that, but all itunes says is "to allow access, please respond on ipad", and the ipad just says "connect to itunes".

Comment: You might make that a separate question on Ask Different. I have no idea.

Comment: It is illegal to jailbreak an ipad.

Comment: @Anonymous "*illegal*" is a strong word to use. While it may contravene Apple's licensing agreement etc, it's not *illegal* per se.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204306

Jailbreaking is unlikely to help in this case.

When you have entered the passcode incorrectly 10 times, the device becomes completely disabled.  Prior to this, you can sometimes connect the device to iTunes and have iTunes reset the passcode lock counter so that you can try again, however, once the 10th incorrect entry has been made, your device will be permanently locked, and will only be able to be used if the device is erased to factory settings in iTunes.

The unfortunate thing is that there is no way to recover the data on the device once it has been activation locked.  If the device was signed into iCloud, you may be able to recover things such as contacts, photos, calendars, and messages, if the sync option was enabled for these items. Quite often, you will find much of the data you are most concerned about is also scattered across other services, such as email, social media, and other cloud storage services if you have made use of such things.

If the device was backed up to either iCloud or iTunes, you may be able to restore the backup, and assuming your passcode attempts were made accidentally (or by curious children) you might attempt to access the device again with all of your data if you can remember the passcode stored in the backup.