# How to restore disabled iPad not visible in Finder on Catalina?

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, restore, catalina

This is similar to 
["iPad is disabled, connect to iTunes"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200758/ipad-is-disabled-connect-to-itunes)

I have a disabled ipad. Music in 10.15.1 does not see the device.
What recorse do I have to either get to touchpad or reset to factory settings?

It's not in finder either(I've just upgraded to 10.15.2).

Answer (score -3):

I gave up and recycled that $400 doorstop.
Thank you apple. But no thanks for bricking my 4 quids.